# fade in/out function

Tags: java, android

I found a few answers about how to create fade in/out, however, since I'm going to use it several times in my class, I'm trying to find a way to create function for it like this:

```
public void fadeout (String res_name, String res_alfa, int res_duration) {
    res_name.animate().alpha(res_alfa).setDuration(res_duration);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is perfectly possible, but you are passing the wrong types in your function. Firstly, you should pass the View object itself instead of it's String res_name. Secondly, res_alpha has to be of float type, not String. Finally, you have to add the call `.start()` at the end. This is how it would look:

```
public void fadeout (View view, float res_alfa, int res_duration) {
        view.animate().alpha(res_alfa).setDuration(res_duration).start();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is missing the start method:

```
public void fadeout (String res_name, String res_alfa, int res_duration) {
    res_name.animate().alpha(res_alfa).setDuration(res_duration).start();
}
```

Comment: The issue is with the animate() function since the resource doesn't exist yet, it gives an error, even after adding the start function at the end.